# How to add blank space between the column names?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I add blank spaces between the columns?

I want to display 3 columns in one column.

```
select artikel_nr || preis || termin from auftragsposition
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate in a space as a text literal:

```
select artikel_nr || ' ' || preis || ' ' || termin from auftragsposition
```